# Headphones not working in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and getting sound through Laptop speakers but not through Headphones.
Laptop: Asus K55VM-SX086D
Headphones: JBL

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type alsamixer , after you do so you'll see the headphones output level. You can increase or decrease the level as needed.